# How can I get the size of an array in codeigniter controller?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I want the array length to be retrieved in the controller function, I tried using    `count($array)`  . But it just returns `0`  independent of the array length. My code,

```
function daybook()
{
  $data['j1'] = $this->lams_master_model->journal_info();
  echo count($j1);
}
```

Somebody please help me on about that..

Comment: `$j1` is undefined. if you define `$data['j1']`, why don't you echo `count($data['j1'])`?

Comment: function [count()](http://www.php.net/count), please edit post and add your model here and lets see where is the problem.

Comment: change the key name j1 to jim and then at view print_r($jim); check it the data is coming or not.

Comment: You can do count`($this->lams_master_model->journal_info())`,`count($data['j1'])` but not count($j1); unless you specified `$j1` somewhere which i do not see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$j1` is not a assigned variable. You probably mean `echo count($data);` or `echo count($data['j1']);`.

Comment: Thankyou , i changed count($j1); to count($data['j1'])` & it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$data['j1'] = $this->lams_master_model->journal_info();
echo count($data['j1']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
count($this->lams_master_model->journal_info());
```

If you are not certain if `lams_master_model->journal_info()` return's a array you could allways check the return value within that function or just `var_dump($this->lams_master_model->journal_info());`

Answer (score 0):

`j1` is the name of array not a variable. So use `echo count($data['j1'])` not `echo count($j1);`. Alternatively you can also return number of rows by `$query->num_rows()` from your model instead of using count in controller. For more details you can see : http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html

Answer (score 0):

you just need to do `print_r(count($data));` instead of `echo count($j1);`.
Have fun.